# what is np.load(opt.test_set)[()] mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
...
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser
parser.add_argument('--test_set', default='liberty', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--test_matches', default='xxxxx.txt', type=str)
...
def main(args):
    opt=parser.parse_args(args)
    ...
    def load_provider():
        p=np.load(opt.test_set)[()]
        for i.t in enumerate(['matches', 'nonmatches']):
            p[t] =p['match_data'][opt.test_matches][i]
        return p
...
if __name__=='__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

So when I cloned the code and downloaded the dataset, `liberty` is a folder with bmp images and txt files, so when I ran the code I got the following error:

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'liberty'
```

I understand `np.load` should read a specific file instead of a directory, but I am trying to understand what `np.load(opt.test_set)[()]` means.

Comment: It's still just a normal `np.load()` call. The *return value of tha call* is then indexed with `[()]` and `()` is just an empty tuple.

Comment: So the equivalent would be: `result = np.load(opt.test_set)`, and `p = result[()]`. Why the result is being indexed with an empty tuple is only known to the authors, we can't see what the `np.load()` call would normally have loaded.

Comment: The necessity of this was a consequence of [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/fa547b80f7035da85f66f9cbabc4ff75969d23cd) commit's underlying issue, I believe.  It's simply a way to return a view of the array whose base is the array.  It has to do with issues handling 0-dimensional arrays

Comment: My guess is that the original `save` was given a dictionary, or a `np.array(adict)`.  So the `[()]` step is removing that dictionary from a 1 element (0d) object dtype array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a regular [`numpy.load()` call](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html), followed by an indexing operation (`[...]`) with an empty tuple.

The following is equivalent, with the parts separated:

```
result = np.load(opt.test_set)
key = ()
p = result[key]
```

Why the code is using an empty tuple as the key into whatever `np.load()` was supposed to return, is not clear without more context.

`np.load()` doesn't support loading directories, full stop, and the code you posted won't do anything different. The value for `opt.test_set` should be pointing to a file, not a directory, see the documentation what *is* supported.

A quick Google points me to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/szagoruyko/cvpr15deepcompare), where the instructions seem to indicate that the Python code is driven by a Lua script that explicitly sets `test_set` to a specific file, see the [*Testing existing models* section](https://github.com/szagoruyko/cvpr15deepcompare/blob/8acbf494b307a648c38a6c8e18c57dfbf8f5eb06/training/README.md#testing-existing-models).